# Iterate through different DOM nodes and elements with php

Tags: php, html, xml, string, dom

I'm trying to create a newsletter based on a time condition. I have an XML file loaded into a DOM document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
<user><mail>sandro.calzada@gmail.com</mail><time>1387814834</time></user><user>       <mail>b4bp_22@hotmail.com</mail><time>1387814834</time></user></users>
```

I wish to iterate through all 'time' tags, also getting values from every 'mail' tag as a string.

This is my first attempt. I am not sure why I failed here but it seems that iteration is working fine for time but leaving mails aside.

```
    $data = new DOMDocument();

$data->load('data.xml');

$times = $data->getElementsByTagName('time');
$emails = $data->getElementsByTagName('mail');

$timestamp = time();
$timestamp1 = $timestamp;
$timestamp = $timestamp-1;

foreach($times as $t)

{

    if($t->nodeValue > $timestamp)

    {

    }

    else if($t->nodeValue < $timestamp)

{

$t->nodeValue = $timestamp1;

$email = $emails->nodeValue;

$to = $email;
```

This is my second attempt. The problem here is that $email can not be converted to a string.

```
$itm = 0;

require_once('functions.php');

$data = new DOMDocument();

$data->load('data.xml');

$times = $data->getElementsByTagName('time');

$timestamp = time();
$timestamp1 = $timestamp;
$timestamp = $timestamp-1;

foreach($times as $t)

{

    if($t->nodeValue > $timestamp)

    {
    $itm = $itm+1;
    }

    else if($t->nodeValue < $timestamp)

{

$t->nodeValue = $timestamp1;

$email1 = $data->getElementsByTagName('mail')->item($itm);

$email = strval($email1);

$itm = $itm+1;

$to = $email;

$unsub = base64_encode($email);
```

Any ideas how I could do this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop might be more appropriate:

```
$times = $data->getElementsByTagName('time');
$emails = $data->getElementsByTagName('mail');

for ($i=0; $i < $times->length; $i++) { 
    $ts = (string) $times->item(0)->nodeValue;
    if ( $ts < time()-1 ) {
        $times->item(0)->nodeValue = $ts;
        $email = $emails->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/82241)

Comment: Only index inside item() is missing :P, but this is the solution many thanks

Comment: [`//user/time[number(.) < 1387896441]/preceding-sibling::mail[last()]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20762674/367456)

Answer (score 0):

I think this way it would be more readable:

```
<?php
$x='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
<user><mail>sandro.calzada@gmail.com</mail><time>1387814834</time></user>
<user>       <mail>b4bp_22@hotmail.com</mail><time>1387814834</time></user></users>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($x);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('user') as $user){
   $mails = $user->getElementsByTagName('mail');
   $times = $user->getElementsByTagName('time');
   print $mails->item(0)->nodeValue. "-". $times->item(0)->nodeValue ."\n";
}
```

You can try here: https://eval.in/82242

Answer (score 0):

I modified Amal code, this is just what I needed.

```
    $times = $data->getElementsByTagName('time');
$emails = $data->getElementsByTagName('mail');

$timestamp = time();

for ($i=0; $i < $times->length; $i++) { 
$ts = (string) $times->item($i)->nodeValue;
if ( $ts < $timestamp-1 ) {
    $times->item($i)->nodeValue = $timestamp;
    $email = $emails->item($i)->nodeValue;

$to = $email;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access XML Elements (and perhaps Attributes) as strings. You've choosen PHP's `DOMDocument` library to parse the XML. [DOM is a standard defined by W3C](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) used not only by PHP but also by many others, for example Mozilla.

To get the string value of an element with DOMDocument, you need to access the `nodeValue` property of a `DOMElement` object (PHP: `DOMElement::$nodeValue`) which is actually part of the `DOMNode` (PHP: [`DOMNode::$noveValue`](http://php.net/domnode#domnode.props.nodevalue)) as `DOMElement` is a sub-type of `DOMNode`. The PHP manual says about `nodeValue`:

> *nodeValue*
>   The value of this node, depending on its type

By *type* this means that if the type is `DOMElement` (as in your case), it will contain the string you're looking for.

So all you need to do is to query all those *email* elements that preceed those *time* elements that are larger (in my example I flip this: lower) than the time to compare against:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$expr  = sprintf(
    '//user/time[number(.) < %d]/preceding-sibling::mail[last()]'
    , time()
);
echo '"', $expr, "\" :\n";

$emails = $xpath->query($expr);
foreach($emails as $email) {
    echo ' * ', $email->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

As this example shows `$email->nodeValue` contains the email address as string. Compare with the exemplary output:

```
"//user/time[number(.) < 1387896441]/preceding-sibling::mail[last()]" :
 * sandro.calzada@gmail.com
 * b4bp_22@hotmail.com
```

The demo is here: https://eval.in/82540

---

For the XML you have in your question, it's most likely easier accessible with a different (but related) XML parser PHP has: *SimpleXML*. Compare with the following example:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$expr  = sprintf(
    '//user/time[number(.) < %d]/preceding-sibling::mail[last()]'
    , time()
);

$emails = $doc->xpath($expr);
foreach($emails as $email) {
    echo ' * ', $email, "\n";
}
```

As this example shows, SimpleXML offers magical `__toString()` methods so that the element object for the email - `$email` - is automatically converted to string when used with `echo`.

Demo is here: https://eval.in/82545